# Hibernate AutoGenerated value not working with Jackson mapper

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

I am just started with using Spring Boot CrudRepository, Now my Enitity having one Unique field(not P.K) FeedID with auto generated value.
When i create a new object manually without setting a FeedID value , it works fine , FeedID automatically generated .
But when i am using JackSon object mapper to convert the request param Json to pojo object directly it showing null/duplicate exception for FeedID field.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/feed/addNewFeed")
public Feed addNewFeed(@RequestParam("Feed") String jsonFeed) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {
    Feed feed = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFeed, Feed.class);         
    return feedRepoImplementation.addNewFeedImpl(feed);     
}
```

**ENTITY**

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int FEED_ID;
    @Id
    @Column(length=100)
    private String URL_LINK;//Primary Key
    private String HEADLINE;
    @Column(length=1500,nullable=false)
    private String CONTENT;
    @Column(length=500,nullable=false)
    private String HEADLINE_IMAGE;  
    private FeedCatagory CATAGORY;
    private String AUTHOUR_NAME;
    private String PUBLISHING_DATE; 
    private String PUBLISHED;
    private int VIEWS;
    private int SHARED;
```

**ERROR**

```
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_6hu52poark0i0f4us9cfql8au'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.feed'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
```

But instead of using the Objectmapper if i create the pojo manually without touching the FeedID field it works fine

```
    Feed feed = new Feed();
    feed.setAUTHOUR_NAME("AUTHOUR");
    feed.setCATAGORY(UtilityHelper.FeedCatagory.SPORTS);
    feed.setPUBLISHING_DATE("12/10/16");
    feed.setCONTENT("CONTENT");
    feed.setURL_LINK("URL-LINK");
    feed.setHEADLINE("HEADLINE");
    feed.setPUBLISHED("TRUE");
    feed.setSHARED(0);
    feed.setVIEWS(0);
    feedRepository.save(feed);
```

What i guess is inside Client JSON i don't have not included auto-generated field 'FeedID' , so obectMapper automatically assigning 0 to that field , but as 0 already exist so duplicate constraint showing. Please Help

Comment: if i pass "feedID":nul inside json it shows null pointer ,

Comment: Your code also leaves the ID to its default value: 0. Why don't you use your debugger to see which value your JSON contains, and which value your ID contains? Also, why don't you respect the Java naming conventions, and why do you send JSON as a request parameter, rather than sending it as the request body directly?

Comment: @Chanky . Did you try feedID with space: `feedID:""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@RequestBody` annotation instead of `@RequestParam` and send JSON from your front-end or postman and hence there will be no need in converting a string to object using `ObjectMapper`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/feed/addNewFeed",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Feed addNewFeed(@RequestBody Feed feed){     
    return feedRepoImplementation.addNewFeedImpl(feed);     
}
```

Also you are using `@GeneratedValue` with your `FEED_ID` field.  `@GeneratedValue` will create unique number if it is used with @Id.

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int FEED_ID;
```

Since you have already `@Id` annotated field  it would be better if you  generate unique number to FEED_ID manually. For this you have to use `@PrePersist` annotation in your entity class like this:

```
@PrePersist
public void initializeFeedId() {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    this.FEED_ID = random.nextInt(1000000000);
}
```

This will generate unique number based on current time.

Comment: Changed RequestMapping with RequestBody , and sending JSON data using body option from POSTMAN , But no luck , same thing happening , https://img42.com/mH27W

Comment: Could you provide complete stacktrace

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: SQL Server. I noticed something ,  right now i have URL_LINK as PK and FEED_ID as AutoGenerate unique integer column,
If i make FEED_ID as PK with AutoGenerate then it's working smooth , Otherwise evertime FeedID is '0' irrespective of AutoGenerate, see the details hibernate logs https://img42.com/w29q1

Comment: Superb , this '@PrePersist' done the trick, actually i did't know that GeneratedValue don't work if not used with Id annotation , sorry for wasting ur time , thanks a lot .